# .Jar File Has Compile Errors When Decompiled But Works Properly

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiler

I downloaded an executable `.jar` file and used the [Java Decompiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Decompiler) to extract the sources. I imported them into Eclipse it shows me a few compile errors such as wrong types or calls to invisible methods. I therefore can't run the project without fixing everything.

How is it possible for the `.jar` file to function properly even though the decompiler clearly shows that there are logical errors? Does it have to do with the compiler level being older (I use 1.8 while it originally has been compiled using 1.6 or 1.7)? Isn't compatibility kept though? Did the decompiler make mistakes?

Comment: The decompiler can make mistakes; plus the code can be deliberately messed with following compilation by an obfuscation tool

Comment: What is an "invisible method"?

Comment: An "invisible method" is probably a [bridge method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html).

Comment: `Did the decompiler make mistakes?` **yes**.

Comment: Also, have you tried Procyon? JD isn't the best.

Comment: @Antimony: I used Procyon and it's significantly better! Still, I needed to fix a few minor errors in the project. This one isn't perfect either. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is it possible for the .jar file to function properly even though the decompiler clearly shows that there are logical errors?

The compiled classes in the .jar file are composed of bytecode, not Java source.  There is no single transform from bytecode back into Java code.  The bytecode may be well-formed, but different decompilers may produce different results, and the results will not always be valid.

> Did the decompiler make mistakes?

Probably.  It happens.  Having written a Java decompiler, I can tell you it is anything but straightforward.